# Ceil to one decimal place

Tags: php, rounding

I have been messing with this calculation trying to round up to one decimal place. But no luck, rounding works fine, but I need to round up.

This is as far as I've gotten, everything else has given much nastier error messages.

```
if (!empty($sum)) {
echo ceil($sum / $line['rate'] * 10, 1)/10; //my problem lies here
$sum1 = round($sum / $line['rate'], 1);
}
```

> Warning: ceil() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must eliminating the second parameter from `ceil`, and it should work fine:

```
echo ceil($sum / $line['rate'] * 10) / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = $sum/$line['rate'];
$value = number_format(intval($value*10)/10, 1);
```